# Assign style to react component like javascript element.style.width = width syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering if there is a way to add styles and attributes to a react component using syntax like the following.

```
const rect = <rect></rect>
rect.style.fill = "black" 
rect.style.height = "50px"
rect.style.width = "50px"
```

This doesn't work (or I wouldn't be asking) but is there something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the react docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, using refs.

```js
const { useEffect, useRef } = React;

const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const rect = <div ref={ref}></div>;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.style.background = "black";
    ref.current.style.height = "50px";
    ref.current.style.width = "50px";
  }, []);
  
  return rect;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```